# Salesforce - FeedbackNotificationMailbox does not compile

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to run some tests. They are failing with an error of:

line -1, column -1: Previous load of class failed: feedbacknotificationmailbox

So I found FeedbackNotificationMailbox under Apex classes. Under Class Summary it says "Does Not Compile". 
This is apparently part of the Salesforce.com API. So can anyone tell me how to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like there's a syntax error within that class - could you post the actual APEX code for it?

Comment: Cheers. That was it. Still pretty new to Salesforce and thought it was a salesforce class because of the text in Version Settings. But I fixed it now. Thanks.

Comment: Going to post my comment as an answer then - gotta get that rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely due to a syntax error within the FeedbackNotificationMailbox apex class. I would check the source for that class, and ensure it can be compiled independently of running your tests.

Also, you may want to check out the [Force IDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE) for your appex development - there's built in intellisense that can warn you of these types of errors in any of your discoverable apex classes and triggers - very handy for writing and running unit tests as well.